# Class variables are unable to perform attribute lookup upon the instance variable

Tags: python, oop

I observed while  playing and learning about the vast topic of python OOP, that a a class variable can be accessed by the class instance created, but the class can't call the instance variable defined with the class

```
class abc():
    height=180
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.age=12 
        self.name=name


ee=abc("Muhammad")
print(ee.height)
print(abc.height)
```

**output**

```
180
180
```

But if I try to access the class variable directly via the class name, it throes an error.

```
ee=abc("Muhammad")
print(ee.height)
print(abc.age)
```

**output**

```
AttributeError: class abc has no attribute 'age'
```

So, I observed this and thought that it would be helpful to share with beginners the depth of python OOP. Please if someone can throw some light on it.

Comment: But I don't understand why you would expect that to work.

Comment: Note that the word "call" in the title is wrong terminology here. You are referring to attribute lookup.

Comment: print(ee.rr) works but instead of the last line print(abc.age) I would rather put print(abc.rr) to show that the class cannot refer to an instance variable

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette was a typo, corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting an attribute with `age = 12` in `__init__`. All you are doing it do define a local variable that will get garbage collected when `__init__` is done.

You'd have to use `abc.age = 12` to actually set an attribute on the class   `abc`
(or `type(self).age = 12`).

I'm assuming this is an educational example, otherwise setting the age in the class for what seems to be modeling persons is not very useful.

Re-setting the class-attribute every time `__init__` is called is redundant as well.

Comment: i understand what you are saying, but its just an example that class cant access the instance variable defined in the class method, am i right?

Comment: @Khan `age = 12` neither sets an instance variable nor a class variable with the name `age`. Btw, `classmethod` has a special meaning. `__init__` is not a classmethod.

Comment: @Khan Classes can't access instance variables at all. They're tied to _instances_, hence the name. You have to _instantiate_ the class (create an instance) to get to them, because they're different for every instance. That's the whole point of them.

Comment: @timgeb , i haven't said age=12 is a class or instance variable. second, i haven't wrote class method (function), instead of classmethod.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist agree to you.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you define a variable in a class, you either define the variable in the scope of the *class* or the scope of the *instance*. The line `height = 180`, defines height in the class scope(class scope is basically the global scope for the class). The lines `self.age = 12` and `self.name = name` defines *age* and *name* in the scope of the instance(instance scope is basically the local scope).

In python if you perform an attribute lookup with an instance(like `ee.height`), the instance first searches for the variable *height* in the instance scope, if it isn't found there then the instance searches in the class scope. However, if you perform attribute lookup with a class(like `abc.age`), the class can't access the local instance scope and hence can search for the variable age only in the class scope. Since there is no variable age in the class scope, it returns an *Attribute Error*.